# How to configure babel7 to support `import {}` from `export default` in javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

I am using `webpack 4` and `babel 7` for a javascript project. I doesn't work when I use `import { ... }` syntax. Below is the source code:

./test.js

```
const a = 1;

export default { a };
```

./index.js

```
import { a } from './test';

console.log(a);
```

The output is `undefined`. It works fine if I change `index.js` as below:

```
import a from './test';

console.log(a.a);
```

I wonder how I should configure `babel7` to support `import {}`. Below is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

I also tried a few plugins but none of them works:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"
  ]
}
```

Below is the dependencies:

```
devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.28.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
```

Below is my webpack configuration for `babel-loader`:

```
module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This has nothing to do with Babel.** The problem is that you need to read up on how named exports work.

```
import { a } from './test';
```

is trying to import the **named** export `a` from `test.js`. The brackets `{}` syntax is for importing **named** exports.

Instead, go with

```
import a from './test';
```

which is the syntax for importing the `default` export,

or change `test.js` to do an export named `a`:

```
const a = 1;

export { a };
```

Your `test.js` only has a `default` export, and none named `a`.

Comment: I have used `export default {}` syntax a lot in the previous version of babel6.

Comment: I also think Zhao Yi also accidentally used the object short hand notation. `export default { a };` default exports an object like: `{a: 1}`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: @axm__ That notation in different contexts has different meanings. In the export context it is not an object property shorthand. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: @connexo you are very right. I forgot that. Sorry for adding confusion!

Comment: @ZhaoYi As I said, you need  to read up on export/import thoroughly.

Comment: @connexo `export default {a}` is equal to `export default {a: a}`. It still doesn't work if I change the `test.js` to `const a = 1; const b = {a: a}; export default b`. How can I use `export default`?

Comment: By using default import too! Man, go read up on import/export! `import a` is importing the default export, `import { a }` is importing the export named `a`. It's all in my answer, did you even read it?

Comment: Yes I did read it. Look, when I use `import { a }` it means import an exported object who has a key named `a`. It is as same as `const v1 = {a: 1}; const { a } = v1`. Is that right? This plugin `https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import` works in previous babel version but the latest babel doesn't have such plugin. So how can I support that?

Comment: *it means import an exported object who has a key named a* **No!** You still don't understand it. In `export { a } ` `{ a }` is **not an object literal**.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the format from this

```
const a = 1;
```

export default { a };

to this

```
const a = require('1') 
module.exports =  { a: {} };
```

also you need to create a intermediate file webpack.config.js

point to  the webpack.config.babel.js file with this code

```
require('babel-register');                                         
module.exports = require('./webpack.config.babel.js');
```